# count aggregate between three date ranges

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query where I want 3 columns of data. day0 to be between now() and - INTERVAL 24 hours
day1 between end of day0 - 48 hours 
and day2 between end of day1 and 72 hours

This is what I have so far.

```
select distinct nc.flowstepname, 
       count(distinct(nc.id)) as day0, 
       count(distinct(nc.id)) as day1, 
       count(distinct(nc.id)) as day2
from sparq.nc nc
where nc.flowstepname like "1%"
    and nc.created > NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOUR
group by nc.flowstepname ASC;
```

Like this:

```
select distinct nc.flowstepname, 
       (select count(distinct(nc.id)) 
        from sparq.nc nc 
        where nc.flowstepname like "1%" 
        and nc.created = now() - interval 24 hour) as day0, 
       (select count(distinct(nc.id)) 
        from sparq.nc nc 
        where nc.flowstepname like "1%" 
        and nc.created = interval 24 hour - interval 48 hour) as day1, 
       (select count(distinct(nc.id)) 
        from sparq.nc nc 
        where nc.flowstepname like "1%" 
        and nc.created = interval 48 hour - interval 72 hour) as day2 
from sparq.nc nc 
group by nc.flowstepname ASC
```

Comment: Please add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: like this select distinct nc.flowstepname, 
  (select count(distinct(nc.id)) from sparq.nc nc where nc.flowstepname like "1%" and nc.created = now() - interval 24 hour) as day0, 
  (select count(distinct(nc.id)) from sparq.nc nc where nc.flowstepname like "1%" and nc.created = interval 24 hour - interval 48 hour) as day1, 
  (select count(distinct(nc.id)) from sparq.nc nc where nc.flowstepname like "1%" and nc.created = interval 48 hour - interval 72 hour) as day2
from sparq.nc nc
group by nc.flowstepname ASC;

Answer (score 1):

You could use COUNT(DISCTINCT(CASE ... WHEN

I've set up next example:

```
CREATE TABLE nc (id int, flowstepname varchar(20), created datetime);

INSERT INTO nc VALUES
(1,  '1152', NOW() - interval 20 hour),
(1,  '1152', NOW() - interval 21 hour),
(2,  '1152', NOW() - interval 22 hour),
(1,  '1152', NOW() - interval 31 hour),
(1,  '1152', NOW() - interval 32 hour),
(1,  '1152', NOW() - interval 34 hour),
(2,  '3154', NOW() - interval 35 hour),
(2,  '1152', NOW() - interval 40 hour),
(1,  '1152', NOW() - interval 49 hour),
(1,  '1152', NOW() - interval 52 hour),
(2,  '4152', NOW() - interval 60 hour),
(3,  '1152', NOW() - interval 65 hour),
(4,  '1152', NOW() - interval 66 hour);

select nc.flowstepname, 
       count(distinct(case when nc.created >= (now() - interval 24 hour) then nc.id else null end)) as day0, 
       count(distinct(case when nc.created < (now() - interval 24 hour) 
                            and nc.created >= (now() - interval 48 hour) then nc.id else null end)) as day1, 
       count(distinct(case when nc.created < (now() - interval 48 hour) 
                            and nc.created >= (now() - interval 72 hour) then nc.id else null end)) as day2
from   nc
where  nc.flowstepname like "1%"
and    nc.created > NOW() - INTERVAL 72 HOUR
group by nc.flowstepname ASC;
```

> ```
> flowstepname | day0 | day1 | day2
> :----------- | ---: | ---: | ---:
> 1152         |    2 |    2 |    3
> ```

<kbd>*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=cba6771196dc8b356bbcdf64f019017f)*</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to mention I'm set in a read only option so I cannot use Create Table  though

Comment: but the rest should work fine

Comment: I've created a table just to show you how it works.

Comment: `day1` can be simplified to `SUM(nc.created < (now() - interval 24 hour) and nc.created >= (now() - interval 48 hour))`.  (etc)